# MP3 плеер под Linux

Tags: linux

Посоветйте хороший аудио mp3 плеер

Comment: Что является критерием "хорошести"?Стабильность или навороченность?Мультифункциональность(Радио,Инет-станции аля Ласт Фм) или заточка только на воспроизведение музыки.Какая у вас графическая среда(окружение)-Гном/Кеды.Уровень своих знаний линупса укажите тоже.Скажите чего вы хотите и Вам предложат решение)))

Comment: ОС Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome версии. Нужно чтобы был эквалайзер, списки воспроизведения и система оценки треков(звездочки были в ритмбоксе), вообщем то все) Знания линукса можно сказать нулевые) Просто я захотел перейти на линукс, тк он мне показался быстрее со всех сторон)

Comment: Энд... читай обзоры http://livenix.blogspot.com/2010/09/linux.html и http://habrahabr.ru/qa/5299/ и комменты)))

Comment: Ритмбокс стоит, но я сколько не пытался а эквалайзер не удалось поставить, он модуль его не видит...

Comment: DeaDBeeF. Ничего лучше покамест не придумали :) ИМХО, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда ритмбокс или Exaile. Второй покрасивше, но написан с примением языка питон, а по отзывам у того проблемы с очисткой памяти. Иначе говоря - память будет утекать. Почитать мона тут http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaile. Ритмбокс попроще, но и побыстрее. Правда есть у него мания - при запуске пересканировть коллекцию (отключается). Потом возможно перейдешь на mpd+sonata|gmpc. Просто, дешево и сердито. И работает и ресурсы по минимуму жрет.

Answer (score 0):

Top 10 Linux MP3 Players » Lindesklindesk.com/.../top-10-linux-mp3-players/ там найдешь что надо

Answer (score 0):

В amarok есть всё вышеперечисленное. Он требует qt, но по моему это не беда.

Comment: В защиту amarok. С выходом КДЕ4 многие его программы потеряли в количестве настроек, кто хочет сохранить функциональность старого КДЕ3.5 обратите внимание на http://www.trinitydesktop.org/

Answer (score 0):

Тоже искал удобный для плеер ... и единственным решением, которым пользуюсь уже года полтора является aimp+wine. работает достаточно бысто, глобыльных проблем (кроме проблемы с паузой - при нажатии на плей после паузы не начинает проигрывать) не замечал.(амарок с каждым годом более заграмождённее, и настроек интерфейса всё меньше)Ещё очень популярным становится Clementine,можете попробывать его

Answer (score 0):

xnoise-аудио проигрыватель основаный на gtk++,с точки зрения хорошести,юзабельности он подходит.К ласт фм ,через аудио скроблер конектится автоматически,что еще,можно добавлять в фонотеку файлы одним кликом(двумя) по файлу,можно переписывать теги к музыке(покрайне мере на файлах MPEG-3),впринцепе он мне нравится,в оф.репозиториях его нету,что есть печально,надо рыскать в интернете,чтобы найти его,ну как говрится-Гугл тебе в помощьсобственно,все библеотеки добавляет автоматически нечего нетребует)оф.сайт xnoise -http://www.xnoise-media-player.com/

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится идейный аналог [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) - [DeaDBeeF](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/). Ест мало памяти, приятный интерфейс, поддерживает глобальные горячие клавиши, играет flac+cue с разбивкой на треки и умеет [ещё кучу всего](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/about.html).

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать **Rhythmbox**

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox

Скриншоты

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Screenshots